# Type Hinting: Use type of a class member as function return type (for inheritance)

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

What is the correct way to reuse the type of a class member to type hint other items in the class? As an example:

```py
from typing import Type

class Model:
    pass

class ChildModel:
    childvar = "Child Model"

class Base:
    var: Type[Model]

    def fn(self) -> ??:
        return self.var

class Child(Base):
    var = ChildModel

    def new_fn(self):
        x = self.fn()  # Type of x should be "ChildModel"
        print(x.childvar)

Child().new_fn() # Prints "Child Model" successfully
```

I am looking for what would work to replace `??` such that the return type of `fn()` can be inferred for all child classes.

MyPy does not accept changing `??` to `Type[Model]` to match `Base.var`: `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Type[ChildModel]", base class "Base" defined the type as "Type[Model]"` (though it is possible I made a mistake here). Even if this were allowed, this would allow `Base.fn()` to return any `Model` or `Model` subclass, not strictly the type of `var` (as defined in a child of `Base`)

Something like `T = TypeVar("T", bound=Type[Model])` seems disallowed without generics, which don't seem quite applicable since the type can be inferred without generic-style specification. I think the solution would likely also work to type hint method arguments, method-local variables, and other class member variables.

What is the best way to do this (if possible)?

Edit: adding clarification, corrected issue with code

Comment: > "but this would allow for returning a different Model subclasses rather than the same kind as var"
Isn't this phrase a bit confusing? If you're using inheritance, this is the expected (and normally) the desired behavior. The `bound=...` should also work, although I found `mypy` doesn't like it too much. Any chance interfaces (ABC) could help you with the typing? If you want `ChildModel`,  your `var` type is off... don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I guess you missed the inheritance in the ChildBase and you're trying to make it dynamically understand `var`?

Comment: @lowercase00 Thank you for the catch - I corrected the code and made some clarification. It seems like MyPy actually fails the example when using `Type[Model]` for the function return hint (though I might have missed something there). `bound=...` does work but only using generics. It seems to me that this wouldn't be necessary since the type can be inferred via the class variable, but this sort of "driving" and "driven" type might just not be possible.

Comment: Yeah, I really can’t say, never tried to make it dynamic like that… In similar situations the parent type helps a lot (ef we usually have a “BaseSchema” type for Pydantic models on SQLAlchemy Mixin on a ‘__schema__’ attribute, a fairly similar situation). The other thing is abstract classes, not the same, but maybe there’s some adjustments that could help as well. Apart from that no other ideas i’m afraid…

Comment: Thanks for the input, yeah it doesn't seem like this is the sort of thing that's common. ABCs would help narrow the scope of the type hint, but I don't think that would necessarily help when a subclass wants to access features of its own `var`. Guess generics are the fallback (though I might open a mypy issue for the Incompatible types error, and see what they say).

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished with Generics.

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound="Model")


class Model:
    pass


class ChildModel(Model):
    childvar = "Child Model"


class Base(Generic[T]):
    var: type[T]

    def fn(self) -> type[T]:
        return self.var


class Child(Base[ChildModel]):
    var = ChildModel

    def new_fn(self):
        x = self.fn()  # Type of x is type["ChildModel"]
        print(x.childvar)


Child().new_fn()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I know that it is possible with generics, but I was unsure whether there's a way to bind a generic-style type to a member variable, rather than  requiring it be specified generic-style in inheritance. Just to avoid duplicate code (typing in two places) and easier subclass-of-subclass usage

Answer (score 1):

Though this probably fails the *"Explicit is better than Implicit"* test, I suppose this will get you what you want while avoiding typing in two places. In this case, rather than defining `var` on the `Child`, the `var` is pulled from the annotation.

Tested on Python 3.10

```py
import typing
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound="Model")


class Model:
    pass


class ChildModel(Model):
    childvar = "Child Model"


class Base(Generic[T]):
    @classmethod
    @property
    def var(cls) -> type[T]:
        for superclass in cls.__orig_bases__:
            if getattr(superclass, "__origin__", None) == Base:
                return typing.get_args(superclass)[0]

    def fn(self) -> type[T]:
        return self.var


class Child(Base[ChildModel]):
    def new_fn(self):
        x = self.fn()  # Type of x is type["ChildModel"]
        print(x.childvar)
```